# How to run a Gulp task before other ones

Tags: gulp

I'm new to the Gulp build system and so far I found it really concise and intuitive to define tasks (compared to alternatives) until I had to start ordering tasks...

I guess, it's a very common use case: I try to run a clean task before running other build tasks.

I first naively wrote something like this (coffeescript):

```
gulp.task 'dist', ['clean:dist', 'copy-libs:dist', 'minify']
```

The problem of course is that all the dependent tasks are run in parallel and there's no guarantee that subsequent tasks will not run before the clean task.

So, what's the solution ?

Answer (score 2):

Ok, answering my own question:

Some people in the community recommend to use the dependency system.
Thus I have to re-write all my tasks and make them depend on the clean task.

But I would like sometimes to run these tasks *without* running the clean task.
This means I have to duplicate these tasks (one version with and one without the dependency).

Frankly speaking, for me this defeats the purpose of using Gulp since I use it mainly for its conciseness, readablity (especially when written in CoffeeScript) and 'code over configuration' approach.

So, the solution for me right now is to use the [run-sequence](https://www.npmjs.org/package/run-sequence/) plugin along with [merge-stream](https://www.npmjs.org/package/merge-stream) to achieve this while keeping a readable and compact build file (see below).

```
gulp.task 'dist', -> runSequence 'clean:dist', ['copy-libs:dist', 'minify']
```

Looks like Gulp 4 will address this with the 'runSeries' and 'runParallel' functions.

Note that I'm using *merge-stream* plugin because one of my tasks (copy-libs) deals with multiple streams. And, a really good advice here, all your tasks should return a stream and only *one* stream (hence merge-stream).

---

Here's my full build file:

```
# Load all required libraries
gulp = require 'gulp'
del = require 'del'
coffee = require 'gulp-coffee'
less = require 'gulp-less'
changed = require 'gulp-changed'
uglify = require 'gulp-uglify'
cssmin = require 'gulp-minify-css'
htmlmin = require 'gulp-htmlmin'
size = require 'gulp-filesize'
runSequence = require 'run-sequence'
merge = require 'merge-stream'

typeIsArray = Array.isArray || ( value ) -> return {}.toString.call( value ) is '[object Array]'
bower = (value) -> # prefix the given path/array with the bower directory
    if !typeIsArray value then "bower_components/" + value else value.map (str) -> bower str

gulp.task 'clean:development', (cb) ->
    del [
        "src/js/*.js", "!src/js/data.js" # in development, delete all .js files except data.js
        "src/css/main.css", "src/css/sidebar.css", "src/css/bootstrap*"
        "src/fonts/"
        "src/js/libs/"
    ], cb

gulp.task 'clean:dist', (cb) ->
    del "build/", cb

gulp.task 'coffee', ->
    gulp.src "src/js/main.coffee"
        .pipe coffee()
        .pipe gulp.dest "src/js"

gulp.task 'less', ->
    gulp.src "src/css/main.less"
        .pipe less()
        .pipe gulp.dest "src/css"

gulp.task 'copy-libs:development', -> # install and copy only the required bower files to the right directory (under src/)
    merge( # here we have to merge the streams otherwise only the latest one will be returned
        gulp.src bower [
                "jquery/dist/*",
                "angular/angular*.{js,js.map}"
                "angular-sanitize/*.{js,js.map}"
                "angular-animate/*.{js,js.map}"
                "bootstrap/dist/js/*"]
            .pipe changed "src/js/libs"
            .pipe gulp.dest "src/js/libs"
        gulp.src bower "bootstrap/dist/fonts/*"
            .pipe changed "src/fonts"
            .pipe gulp.dest "src/fonts"
        gulp.src bower ["bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css*", "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"]
            .pipe changed "src/css"
            .pipe gulp.dest "src/css"
    )

gulp.task 'watch', ->
    gulp.watch "src/js/main.coffee", ['coffee']
    gulp.watch "src/css/main.less", ['less']

gulp.task 'minify', ['coffee', 'less'], ->
    merge(
        gulp.src "src/js/main.js"
            .pipe uglify()
            .pipe gulp.dest "build/js"
        gulp.src "src/css/main.css"
            .pipe cssmin()
            .pipe gulp.dest "build/css"
        gulp.src "src/index.html"
            .pipe htmlmin {collapseWhitespace: true, removeComments: true}
            .pipe gulp.dest "build"
    )

gulp.task 'copy-libs:dist', ['copy-libs:development'], ->
    # the 'base' option here is used to keep the structure under the src/ directory (otherwise it is flattened)
    gulp.src ["js/data.js", "js/libs/*", "fonts/*", "css/bootstrap.min.css"], {cwd: "src", base: "src"}
        .pipe size()
        .pipe gulp.dest "build"


# Main tasks
gulp.task 'default', -> console.log 'no-op default task'
gulp.task 'clean', ['clean:development', 'clean:dist']
gulp.task 'development', -> runSequence 'clean:development', ['copy-libs:development', 'coffee', 'less', 'watch']
gulp.task 'dist', -> runSequence 'clean:dist', ['copy-libs:dist', 'minify']
```

Comment: It helps if you think of everything not as a task, but as a function. e.g. You can define a `build` function once, then define two tasks which use the `build` function, one of which depends on `clean`, one of which does not.